# Memory Issue Possibly Related RxCocoa Binding Method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have this binding method of RxCocoa:

```
   func bindTableView() {
        data.asObservable()
            .bind(to: tableView
                    .rx
                    .items(cellIdentifier: dealCellID, cellType: DealTabCell.self)
            )
        {
            row, profileData, cell in
            cell.configureProfile(dataModel: profileData)
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Data comes from Firebase but it loads at once and as I scroll down memory use goes up to over 1.7 GB. I thought reusable cells automatically take care of the memory because if you are not seeing a cell it doesn't use memory.

Firebase closure:

```
db.collectionGroup("deals").whereField("Sender", isEqualTo: senderEmail!).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error?.localizedDescription collectiongroup = \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            self.dealNumber = snapshot?.documents.count ?? 0
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dealsPosted.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
                    .bold("\(self.dealNumber)\n")
                    .normal("Deals")
            }
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                if let sender = data["Sender"] as? String,
                   let image = data["ImagePath"] as? String,
                   let dealTitle = data["DealTitle"] as? String,
                   let dealDesc = data["DealDesc"] as? String,
                   let storeID = data["StoreID"] as? String,
                   let storeTitle = data["StoreTitle"] as? String,
                   let dealID = data["DealID"] as? String,
                   let userName = data["UserName"] as? String,
                   let distance = data["Distance"] as? Double,
                   let senderUID = data["SenderUID"] as? String {
                    
                    self.getImageFromURLfromFirebase(path: image, dealTitle: dealTitle, dealDesc: dealDesc, storeTitle: storeTitle, storeID: storeID, dealID: dealID, sender: sender, userName: userName, distance: distance, senderUID: senderUID)
                }
```

In that getImageFromURLfromFirebase method I just download image from url and behavior relay accepts another value. I can provide additional code. That means in the loop of that firebase method every time something like this works:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    userDealsRelay.accept(userDeals.removingDuplicates())
                }
```

That object is this:

```
let userDealsRelay : BehaviorRelay<[DealModel]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [])
```

I am sure the memory usage is caused by tableview because it only happens when I scroll down.
By the way it stops when I am at the bottom and go up again. it is not infinitely growing.

```
struct DealModel: Hashable {
    var storeID: String?
    var dealImage: UIImage?
    var dealTitle: String?
    var dealDesc: String?
    var dealID : String?
    var storeTitle: String?
    var sender: String?
    var userName: String?
    var distance: Double?
    var senderUID: String?
    
    init(storeID: String?, dealImage: UIImage?, dealTitle: String?, dealDesc: String?, dealID: String?, storeTitle: String?, sender: String?, userName: String?, distance: Double?, senderUID: String?) {
        self.storeID = storeID
        self.dealImage = dealImage
        self.dealDesc = dealDesc
        self.dealTitle = dealTitle
        self.dealID = dealID
        self.storeTitle = storeTitle
        self.sender = sender
        self.userName = userName
        self.distance = distance
        self.senderUID = senderUID
    }
}
```

and

```
let profileData: DealModel
```

Comment: Show us the type definition for `DealModel` and `profileData`?

Comment: added those in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with RxCocoa's binding method.

Your `DataModel` holds a UIImage. You are downloading the image for each cell and the caching the image in the DataModel. Therefore, your memory should increase as more cells are displayed. This would happen even if you weren't using Rx.

Comment: perhaps I should save those images to local file of the app?

Comment: Most of the time, what I do is wait to download the image until after the cell is being built and throw it away when the cell goes out of scope. Your typical user, unlike your typical tester, isn't scrolling all over the place. They are looking for something specific and then stop or browsing, which means they don't go back up. However, saving the images to temp storage is a good idea for some use-cases.